# Is my AC not controlled by a breaker?

Tags: electrical

The 2 240v-breakers labeled "AC" do not control the ACs. No idea what they do. No other 240v breakers control the AC either. I tested the breakers with a multi-meter. They turned on and off correctly. There are two switches near the AC outdoor units, which can shut the ACs off, but they are not breakers and can't protect from circuit overload. Where could be breakers for the ACs? Or the ACs are hard wired? However, I didn't see any such connections in the breaker box. It is a single family house, so unlikely to be mis-connected with other houses. I am really puzzled.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the A/C disconnect switches?

Comment: I've come across this in the past. There were a few manufacturers that actually made 120v ac units. Did you check to make sure that the units are actually 240 and not 120?

Answer (score 2):

What do the switches that control the units look like? If there are two individual switches that feed power to the unit, it's possible that each switch is fed from two different 120 volt, single pole breakers. If this is the case, there also may be other loads, such as lights or receptacles, on each 120 volt circuit. This would be an unacceptable installation practice and would also be a violation of the National Electrical Code.

Comment: I think Mike is on the track of what has happened here. And correct about the Code. You need to trace the cable coming from the A/C to determine which breaker(s) it is going to. If it is on two individual breakers they should at least have a handle installed on them so they can't trip individually.